# Calling forms from Radio buttons

Tags: pdf

I have 2 fully completed PDF forms (English and French)  (created using Livecycle, both contain imported artwork)

How would I compile these into 1 form and have radio buttons select either the English or French 
form?

Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to Livecycle and do not have any formal training (as of yet)

Any input would be greatly appreciated,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your question is appropriate for SO, but here is a video about radio buttons in LiveCycle designer where the radio buttons turn the visiblity of content on/off (I am not affiliated).

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hS4LUXJ4dYw&feature=related